# The simple query taking longer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running a simple query and its taking very long time to execute the result:

```
Select MTL_CONTENT_LPN from reporting.DWH_FACT_INV_TRANSACTIONS  
where to_char(MTL_TRANSACTION_DATE,'yyyymm')=(select to_char(Max(SYSDATE),'YYYYMM') from dual)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using sysdate with dual.

You need to use it in following way.

```
Select MTL_CONTENT_LPN from 
reporting.DWH_FACT_INV_TRANSACTIONS  
where MTL_TRANSACTION_DATE between trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH') AND add_month(trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH'),1) - 1
```

By using this where clause, any index on `MTL_TRANSACTION_DATE` will be used to increase the performance.

Cheers!!

Comment: I got your point here however the data I am getting now is for first day of the month only. I want for entire month:

Select distinct MTL_TRANSACTION_DATE
from reporting.DWH_FACT_INV_TRANSACTIONS  
where MTL_TRANSACTION_DATE 
between trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH') 
AND add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH'),1) - 1

Comment: @Tejash You can have functional index on this clolumn like `to_char(MTL_TRANSACTION_DATE,'yyyymm')`. Then index will be used.

Comment: Yes, But that will be again not good for the performance of the overall inserts

Comment: I am using below query for previous year data (2018) basis  on the above mentioned query but seems not getting actual result:

Select count(*) from   --TPSH / 2 SEC
reporting.DWH_FACT_INV_TRANSACTIONS  
where MTL_TRANSACTION_DATE between trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR') AND add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR'),12) - 2